# What does vanilla mean?

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

The *vanilla* adjective appears in many places: plain-vanilla java, vanilla javascript: what does it exactly mean?

From context, is seems to stand for something "plain".

When is a specific code considered *vanilla* and when is it not? Plain, like not wrapped in a framework?

Comment: Plain, like *not using* a 3rd-party library.

Comment: For example: Vanilla Javascript, not using JQuery and alike.

Comment: So when I use Struts and Spring, that's not vanilla java?

Comment: @QuestionEverything: correct

Comment: @QuestionEverything Those are 3rd-party libraries, so: no, not "vanilla" Java.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

> Computer software, and sometimes also other computing-related systems
> like computer hardware or algorithms, is called **Vanilla** when not
> customized from its original form, meaning that it is used without any
> customizations or updates applied to it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software

Comment: This is correct for software, but doesn't exactly match the usage when used with programming languages ;)

Comment: Customization is too generic in this context. I would rather say: vanilla refers to using plain code, without 3rd party libraries or frameworks.

Comment: That's weird. I'm 100% certain that when I programmed on the Commodore Amiga some 35 years ago, VANILLAKEY meant (pre)processed ASCII codes obtained through the keymap from the RAWKEY codes. Thus, the opposite: Vanilla = processed, as opposed  Raw = origin.

Answer (score 49):

*Vanilla* often refers to *pure* or *plain*. So in terms of programming languages, it means either *without the use of 3rd party libraries* or *without the use of frameworks*.

Comment: This is Java specific. My answer talks about programming languages in general and prefixed the statement with "often".

Comment: In context of JavaScript it still hold true, 'pure JS' often refers to 'without JQuery / Prototype / <insert your favorite framework here>', while 'vanilla' often also refers to the environment, e.g. Rhino or else.

Comment: It's a mistake to limit this question to just a couple of languages

Answer (score 30):

It derives from the time when, of the various flavours of ice-cream available, vanilla flavour was the most common, simple and often even the only one available. Other flavours were rarer and more exotic.

In programming terms it does not refer to anything specific but implies any or all of:

- No bells and whistles
- No extra (perhaps unnecessary) features
- Uses no external libraries
- The pure language without any extras

Despite how boring "vanilla" might be seen in terms of ice-cream, it's rarely used derogatively in programming.

Answer (score 0):

I know this a very old post but for posterity purposes. Simply put Vanilla is the raw, un-altered, plain, form of a thing without modification. E.g : vanilla js means javascript as it is without frameworks like react, jquery, etc and vanilla sql means sql without orm like laravel eloquent for instance.

Comment: Except on the AmigaOS/Intuition where VANILLAKEY codes are the "cooked" ASCII codes obtained according to the keymap from the RAWKEY codes issued by the keyboard...

Answer (score -4):

In computer science, vanilla is the term used to refer when computer software and sometimes also other computing-related systems like computer hardware or algorithms are not customized from their original form, i.e., they are used without any customizations or updates applied to them. (Wiki)