# How to determine file exist in public directory for Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some image files in public/image directory, so I want to determine if a file exist in that directory before I save a new file.
How to determine if a file exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Laravel's storage Facade as [**El_Matella**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4547701/el-matella) suggested. However, you could also do this pretty easily with [**"vanilla"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20836115/what-does-vanilla-mean) PHP, using PHP's built-in **[`is_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php)** function :

```
if (is_file('/path/to/foo.txt')) {
    /* The path '/path/to/foo.txt' exists and is a file */
} else {
    /* The path '/path/to/foo.txt' does not exist or is not a file */
}
```

Answer (score 11):

`file_exists(public_path($name)`

here is my solution to check if file exists before downloading file.

```sh
if (file_exists(public_path($name)))
    return response()->download(public_path($name));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Storage Facade:

```
Storage::disk('image')->exists('file.jpg'); // bool
```

If you are using the disk `image` as shown above, you need to define a new disk in your `config/filesystems.php` and add the following entry in your `disks` array:

```
'image' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/image'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Here is the documentation if you want to know more on that Facade:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little utility to check if the directory is empty.

```
if($this->is_dir_empty(public_path() ."/image")){ 
   \Log::info("Is empty");
}else{
   \Log::info("It is not empty");
}

public function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  if (!is_readable($dir)) return NULL; 
  $handle = opendir($dir);
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
     if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
     return FALSE;
     }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497733/how-can-use-php-to-check-if-a-directory-is-empty)